# Get screen resolution of multiple displays

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, screen-resolution, multiple-monitors

I am trying to get the screen monitor resolution using Java. The problem is that I don't get the correct output. The first of the total three monitors is shown with a pixel width of 5760 instead of 1920. They all have the same size 1920x1080.

Code:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
System.out.println("Number of devices: " + gs.length);
System.out.println("Default resolution: " + java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
for (int i = 0; i < gs.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("id: %s, width: %d, height: %d\r\n", gs[i].getIDstring(), gs[i].getDisplayMode().getWidth(), gs[i].getDisplayMode().getHeight());
}
```

Output:

```
Number of devices: 3
Default resolution: java.awt.Dimension[width=5760,height=1080]
id: :0.0, width: 5760, height: 1080
id: :0.1, width: 1920, height: 1080
id: :0.2, width: 1920, height: 1080
```

Any hint on how to get all three correct monitor pixel sizes?

**EDIT 1:**

The output of `xrandr` is:

```
myuser@mysystem ~ $ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
HDMI-2 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93
```

Comment: what does `xrandr` say? Please paste output with different monitor combination. Like 3rd, 1+3, 2+1. Btw you can use printf instead of string concat

Comment: @deathangel908 Check EDIT 1.

Comment: @deathangel908 I just see that besides `HDMI-0`, `HDMI-1`, and `HDMI-2` there also is a `Screen 0` that has exactly 5760x1080 and I wonder if this is the setting I falsely get from `GraphicsEnvironment`.

Comment: What's the output of your java program for `Like 3rd, 1+3, 2+1`? Does it incorrectly output for your specific monitor?

Comment: @deathangel908 I don't understand what you mean with `3rd, 1+3, 2+1`. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Plug out 1st and 2nd monitor ( I mean physically pull out the cable) and run your program. Then do this operation with different combinations of monitors. Thus you can check on which specific case java outputs incorrect value.